# Execute long command in php without being blocked

Tags: php, windows, command, long-integer

I want to run a shell command in PHP but that command takes a while to be performed. So i want it to run in the background but I also want the user to be informed of what is going on. The shell command I am using outputs text describing what it's doing. My question: How can I execute that shell command in the background from my Browser and still have all the verbose from that command being written to my webpage as the command is running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`popen`](http://de.php.net/popen) and then read from the process' output stream and write to the response.